# How to implement "Next" and "Previous" pagination with Angular + NgRx

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am working on Angular project which uses NgRx to cache data. On a Submit button event, I need to fetch 20 records from server and display it. Now, I need to implement pagination(Next and Previous only) for next iteration. When I make a next request, I want to append the response to cache(NgRx store) so that I don't have to make request to backend for "Previous" page. In short, If cache already contains records, I don't want to make request to server. Where and how should I implement pagination logic? In a component or using Router Resolver?

My current implementation(not working) is:

```
constructor(
  private store: Store<AppState>,
  private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
  private router: Router
  ) {
  this.guestAds$ = this.store.select(guestAds); 
  this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: any) => {
   if (Object.keys(params).length) {
     this.queryParams = params;
     this.getAds();
   }
 });
}

onSubmit() {
  const form = this.searchForm.value;
  const queryParams = {
    searchTerm: form.searchTerm,
    category: form.category,
    subCategory: form.subCategory,
    limit: 20,
    startAt: 0,
    prevKeys: ''
  };
  this.router.navigate(['/'], { queryParams });
}

getAds() {
  this.guestAds$
    .pipe(
      tap(ads => {
        if (ads.length) {
          ads.forEach(ad => {
            if (ad.createdAt === Number(this.queryParams.startAt)) {
              console.log('Data alreadyd available');
              /* some logic */
            } else {
              this.store.dispatch(LoadAds({payload: this.queryParams}));
            }
          });
        }
      }),
    ).subscribe(/* I dont know if this is required?! */);
}
```

My NgRx Effect looks like this:

```
loadAds$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(GuestAdsActions.LoadAds),
    mergeMap((action) => this.guestAdsService.getAds(action.payload)
      .pipe(
        map((payload: any) => payload.data),
        map((payload: Ad[]) => GuestAdsActions.LoadAdsSuccess({ payload }),
        catchError(() => of(GuestAdsActions.LoadAdsSuccess({ payload: []}))
        )
      )
    )
  )));
```

My service looks like this:

```
getAds(queryParams: QueryParams) {
  console.log(queryParams);
  return this.http.get(`${this.BASE_URL}/ads`, { params: { ...queryParams } });
}
```

I am calling getAds() method based on router query parameters change listener. What am I doing wrong? I would really appreciate if someone could help me on this. Thank you!

**Edit**: Added Effect and Service

Comment: Do you use `Ngrs Effects`? If not `Effects` has uses for cases like yours.

Comment: @Eldar Yes, I do. How can I make use of Effect efficiently in this case? I've edited mu question. Please have a look at Effect.

Comment: One key question to help you to the end result. --- Does the server offer paginated results? If it does the rest is easy, manage pagination in your component i.e. current page, limit and offset. Then dispatch an action with the pagination properties as props, this will then be picked up by your effects to make a call to the service passing on the pagination properties. Once you have the results back,  create a new state that now contains previous state entities and new entities retrieved from the server. You can take a look at infinite scroll in angular for ideas on pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Well it will be complicated but i will try to describe.

> 1. Change your state to save your `GuestAd` from `Array` to `Map`

```typescript
export interface State {
... // other properties
guestAds : Map<string,Array<GuestAd>>;

}
```

> 2. Change your reducer to handle map operations :

```typescript
... // some other reducer cases
case GuestAdsActions.LoadAdsSuccess:
      const key = JSON.stringify(action.payload); // since your parameter object is complex better using string equality.
      if (state.guestAds.has(key )) { // if exists do not modify 
        return state;
      } else {
        const cloneSet = new Map(state.guestAds);
        cloneSet.set(key, action.data);
        return {...state, guestAds: cloneSet};
      }
```

> 3. Add another selector that accepts parameters

```typescript
export const selectMappedGuestAds = createSelector(guestAds, (mappings, props) => mappings.get(JSON.stringify(props.payload));
```

> 4. Modify effects to check if data available :

```typescript
loadAds$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(GuestAdsActions.LoadAds),
    withLatestFrom(this.store.select(guestAds), (action,data)=>{
     const key = JSON.stringify(action.payload); // again we need to stringify
     return data.has(key ) && data.get(key).length > 0 ? null : action;
}), // check store if has it? if has cached data return null 
fiter(action=> !!action), // if result not null then we need to request it from server    
    switchMap((action) => this.guestAdsService.getAds(action.payload)
      .pipe(
        map((payload: any) => payload.data),
        map((payload: Ad[]) => GuestAdsActions.LoadAdsSuccess({ payload }),
        catchError(() => of(GuestAdsActions.LoadAdsSuccess({ payload: []}))
        )
      )
    )
  )));
```

> 5. Finally change your store request into parametered one :

```typescript
this.store.select(selectMappedGuestAds,{payload:queryParams});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I will try to implement your suggestion and get back to you. This might take some time for me to digest. Thank you!

Comment: `ithLatestFrom(this.store.select(guestAds), action,data=>` here, `action` is not a known element. What is being imported here?

Comment: @CularBytes It's been a while since I post that, I don't think it's an import, it must be a typo that misses paranthesis.